# Wildfly logging pattern elements - Is there a documentation?

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10

I am using Wildfly 10.1 and I would really like to know what logging pattern elements i could use.

I found this documentation here: 
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html
referenced by a Wildfly book.

But this can not be the whole truth, because there are more elements than mentioned there, for example the %s or %E Elements.

I also found this
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html
but that cant be the truth eiter, because the mentioned 
%throwable{short.className} does not work.

Also the Wildfly Documentation at
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Handlers#Handlers-formatter
does not say a word about what pattern elements are available.

I try to create a logging pattern which will generate only one line per exception (no stack trace) but still contain the Message of the exception and the Class, Method and Line Number.

Comment: Unfortunately at this point there is no documentation for it. Though it's definitely on the TODO list. There is also not a default way to only log the `Throwable.getMessage()`. You'd have to write a custom-formatter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so I know I can stop looking for it. But while we are at it, could you point me in the direction to find the source that parses the pattern String? Maybe I can figure it out by reading the source.

Comment: Sure thing. The current upstream is https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logmanager/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/logmanager/formatters/FormatStringParser.java#L84-L197

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much!

Comment: So, this almost looks like logback.  Is there a reason wildfly isn't just depending on the logging facility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now there is a document for logging formatters. [Wildfly Logging Formatters](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/_admin-guide/subsystem-configuration/Logging_Formatters.adoc#pattern-formatter)

You could use `%l` for location information, but there is no pattern for exception message without stacktrace.

Here is the relevant parts from the document;

> %l: The location information. This includes the callers class name, method name, file name and line number.
>
> %m: The formatted message including any stack traces.
>
> %s: The simple formatted message. This will not include the stack trace if a cause was logged.
>
> %e: Prints the full stack trace.
>
> %e{0}: Prints the stack trace ignoring any suppressed messages.
>
> %e{1}: Prints the stack trace with a maximum of one suppressed message.